# inner join in two tables sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, join

I am currently working in `sql` and I want to learn joins. I started with `inner join` and I have a very basic question:

```
select distinct brandname from zonerpm where 
trainer=@tname and companyname=(select id from companydetails where comname=@companyname)
```

I want to join the statement and I want to learn how joins work.

I want to learn how it works and stackoverflow is the best platform for this i can join when the statement have one where clause but this statement have two where clause it is here where i strucked.

Comment: You need to have common columns in those tables to join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using subquery,sql consider subquery as different query
subquery is not a good idea it takes much time rather than join.
if you have column in `brandname` table which contain `companydetails` table  `foreignkey` 
than you can try below query.

```
select distinct zonerpm.brandname,companydetails.id from zonerpm 
inner join companydetails ON zonerpm.company_id=companydetails.id
where trainer=@tname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select distinct z.brandname from zonerpm z left join companydetails cd 
   on cd.companyname=z.companyname where  
   z.trainer=@tname;
```

z is the objectname for zonerpm 
cd is the objectname for companydetails